# What is the source of the vocals used in Sahara by Astrix?

Tags: electronic-music

There are vocals during Astrix's [Sahara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_ehdwsv5BI), specifically at [3:45](https://youtu.be/5_ehdwsv5BI?t=227). These vocals sound like vocals I heard in an Anime movie once. Can anyone confirm the source of these vocals?

While on the same topic, aren't artists required to disclose the source of used material in their music?

Comment: Don't eliminate the possibility that the Astrix song came first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaval sviri is what you looking for